# How to get a note or comment

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I have an Excel containing cell comments/notes, I've uploaded it to Google Drive, and converted it into a Google Spreadsheet. How may I retrieve the comments for cell A1?

The [API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en) doesn't describe how to get a note or comment from a cell.

Comment: Did you try https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/get and https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/list . You can get list of comments in a spread sheet, and you can get particular comment too. But you should use Drive API. I dont think with spread sheets API you can do this.

Comment: As of October 2019, it is still only possible to interact with notes, not with comments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Google Apps Spreadsheet API only provides programmatic access to spreadsheet data. You cannot access comments using the API.

You *can* get the Notes for a cell or range of cells using Google Apps Script. See the [Class Range documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) for these methods:

- getNote() - Returns the note associated with the given cell.
- getNotes() - Returns the notes associated with the cells in the range.

There are open issues related to this functionality, mainly concerning comments (the "other" type of note). See [Issue 1818](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1818) and [Issue 2566](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2566)

In a comment on your question, SGC asks if you've looked at  [developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/get) and [developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/list); these are FILE level comments, not the comments attached to a spreadsheet cell.

Comment: Apparently it's still not possible to work with "comments". Only "notes" are supported.

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a muck around but it's possible to download the googlesheet as a .xlsx file, which, with varying degrees of success, converts the comments into Excel comments.

Uploading this xslx file converts the comments to notes!

[image: Comments-to-Notes]

Comment: 'Unfortunately' Google has since fixed this conversion bug and now Excel comments are converted to comments instead of notes.

Answer (score 3):

1 - Add the following custom function to your spreadsheet (through the Tools -> Script Editor menu)

```
function getNote(cell) {
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getComment()
}
```

2 - on your spreadsheet use the following formula to get contents

```
=getNote(cell("address",a1))
```

or

```
=getNote(cell("address",E9),GoogleClock())
```

if your comments are not static.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work - I get an error ("loading data") as the script is executed.

My use case is to change color of a cell if a comment is present, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between Note and Comment.
getNote is working fine. You create a Note by using the cell menu "insert Note" , and not "insert Comment"

Very sad, but there is no getComment. The example of Oren did not work for me either.