# How to count an amount of comments or specific words written by Accounts in Google sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, drive

I am trying to count comments or specific words written by users in Google Sheet table. for example 5 accounts have permission on sheet and i want to count how many comments or yes/no is written in table by each user. is there any solution for this task?

Comment: I don't think you can access comments via the API [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359481/how-to-get-a-note-or-comment/32444081#32444081).

Comment: Are the yes/no responses accessible with range.getValues and are they the only text within those cells?

Comment: yes/no are only text

Answer (score 1):

This will get the yes/no count case insensitive and it also has two arrays (yays and nays) which contain the row and column of each yes/no response.  Also gets the Users email address.

```
function getYesAndNo() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var yays=[];
  var nays=[];
  var yay=/yes/i;
  var nay=/no/i;
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[i].length;j++)
    {
      if(String(rngA[i][j]).match(yay))
      {
        yays.push([Number(i+1),Number(j+1)]); //rows and columns not indexes
      }
      if(String(rngA[i][j]).match(nay))
      {
        nays.push([Number(i+1),Number(j+1)]); //rows and columns not indexes
      }
    } 
  }
  Logger.log(yays);
  Logger.log(nays);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('User Email = ' + user + ' Yes Count = ' + yays.length + ' No Count = ' + nays.length);
}
```