# Is there an example function using the Google Drive API to read comments from google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to read comments from multiple google sheets using scripts and store text in another google sheet.

I know there is a .getNote() method and not a .getComment() method but I have read on a few posts there is a way to read the comments using Google Drive API but have not seen an example.

Comment: I looked at the API explorer and I couldn't find any obvious way to get comments.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359481/how-to-get-a-note-or-comment) briefly touches upon a method to export google sheet to xlsx format but also suggests that it doesn't always get all of the comments.

Comment: The post I was refering to is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556476/google-apps-script-spreadsheet-comment-automation. "Using Google Drive API in Google Apps Script, we could create Comments in a Google Document.
And after a test, I confirm you can also do it in a Spreadsheet (which is normal because Comments depends only on Drive API)"